# Flurry isn't reflecting in DASHBOARD

Tags: android, dashboard, flurry

I have integrated Flurry SDK successfully in Eclipse. Earlier it used to reflect properly in DASHBOARD, but now its not reflecting the "Active Users" in DASHBOARD.

Here are some codes which I've used :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle     savedInstanceState)
{   
    //   flurry inint
    FlurryAgent.init(this, Constants.MY_FLURRY_APIKEY);
}

//For Flurry Integration 
@Override
public void onStart()
{
   super.onStart();
   FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, Constants.MY_FLURRY_APIKEY);

   FlurryAgent.logEvent("Dialer");
}

//  @Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this); 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.[Here you can see Active User is not reflecting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsImz.png)

Comment: add `FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);` to your code and see if the logs show anything suspectful

Comment: Thank you for reply

but where do i write that:
OnCreate() or OnStart

Comment: after you start session

Comment: how long does it take to reflect in DASHBOARD?

Comment: min 4-5 hours. active users though is relative property. it can take 2-3 days even to calculate it properly.

Comment: Thanx @Shubhank, it worked.

Comment: i wan to use this functionality in each and every class. is it possible. i mean how shall i optimize the code?